# How can i set encoding for Table and row using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, encoding

I am new in java Hibernate and i try to make simple `Hello world` project.

I make a UserClass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table_User")
public class Table_User extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public Table_User(){
       //default  constructor
    }


    public TableUser(String name){
      this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){ return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name){ this.name=name; }


}
```

I am generate table using `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`.

My question is.

How can i SET encoding for table and row `name`?

I want set `utf8_czech_ci` but is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Thank you for your reply!

EDIT, my `persisence.xml` file is:

```
    <persistence-unit name="org.my"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="true" />

            <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Could you put here your `persistence.xml` file?

Comment: @MateuszKorwel sure, i editet. look.

Comment: Specify the "characterEncoding" to be "utf8" (or perhaps "UTF-8", check the Hibernate manual).

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is always set at database level, not in the Hibernate mapping.
If you are using [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html), you can set it as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_czech_ci;
```